# Not able to upload csv bigger than 8MB file

Tags: php, apache, csv, magento

I have created a custom module in magento and it has an option of import csv file.
it uploads file upto 8MB but when i try to upload bigger than 8MB file, it uploads the file in directory but doesn't make any entry in database.

I have set those configuration in php.ini but still no luck.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 24M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 3000
```

Please help

Comment: does you have added like `php_value upload_max_filesize280M` or `php_value upload_max_filesize 280M` ?

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right `php.ini` file? Check which config file is loaded with `phpinfo();`. You also need to restart your webserver after altering your `php.ini`

Comment: yes i have checked php info and it's showing same values those i set @Timothy

Comment: i have added that value in upload_max_filesize to 20M which i can check in phpinfo @GokulShinde

Comment: does your form have enctype="multipart/form-data"?